# How do I know if several zip files are meant to be opened together?

Tags: zip, 7-zip

I have a few zip files and am wondering if there is a way to verify if they are mean't to be open together. For example, if you go to Google Drive and download something, they normally will split the files after it gets too big. If I have three files, `file1.zip`, `file2.zip`, and `file3.zip`, normally trying to open and extract `file2.zip` results in corrupt/incomplete errors. Are there certain headers or indicators to see if they are all linked? If they are linked I would normally use a command in terminal like

```
7za x \*.zip
```

to open them.

Comment: You can use a hex editor to look at the files. zip files usually start with the letters `PK`. But if a zip file was split into several files, only the first one will start with `PK` and the others will have random characters at the start.

Comment: I suppose your best source here is the PK format: pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT. Section 8.3.3. If you're trying to automate the parsing from the command line/batch file in some way: `7z.exe l filename` will give you info on the index and number of volumes so you could use that. As per the suggestion from @SpiderPig. You could use the native command line tool certutil.exe and pipe to find.exe to look for the PK header, e.g. certutil -dump file.zip.001 | find "000000 50 4b"